# Is there a way to add each value to the first one in the for loop in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, console.log

I have 4 different values, when looping through an array. Is it possible to add the values together like you would in Java's StringBuilder append?

I want something like this when doing a console.log():

```
28.0334307,-25.872523799999996, 28.031527552564445,-25.87632233243363
```

Now I am just getting it one for one like this when doing a console.log():

```
28.0334307
-25.872523799999996
28.031527552564445
-25.87632233243363
```

Here is my code:

```
var coordinates = [28.0334307, -25.872523799999996, 28.031527552564445, -25.87632233243363]

for(var item in coordinates)
{
   console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: `console.log(coordinates.toString())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get a string in-line separated by a comma with join() method, try this:

```js
var coordinates = [28.0334307, -25.872523799999996, 28.031527552564445, -25.87632233243363]
console.log(coordinates.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var coordinates = [28.0334307, -25.872523799999996, 28.031527552564445, -25.87632233243363]

console.log(coordinates.join(' '));
```

```js
var coordinates = [28.0334307, -25.872523799999996, 28.031527552564445, -25.87632233243363]

console.log(coordinates.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser consoles displays an array like that in to be more readable. It's not an actual structural representation of how an array is. What you want is basically a string created by joining the elements of the array.
Array.join method can be used for this:

```
coordinates.join("'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript array `join()` method to display values separated by comma.
The `join()` method returns the array as a string.
The elements will be separated by a specified separator. The default separator is a comma (`,`).